# What should our chatroom name be?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chat

Right now our chat room's name is just [Ebooks](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12058/ebooks). I feel there is something better we could name our chat room. What name could we use?

Comment: Answers with multiple options, are less than helpful.  Please post a separate answer for each name suggestion.

Comment: Can someone edit the question for this request instead of posting this under every answer?

Comment: @Matt_2.0 that is good suggestion, but only the OP and moderators currently have edit rights on meta

Comment: @Matt_2.0 This isn't really a feature - req. That's why its tagged discussion

Comment: I was going to suggest 'eRoom' but it looks like there are commercial usages of the word, so it may be trademarked.

Comment: Do we have enough of a consensus to change the name at this point

Comment: @DVK I would say yes, 'The Library' is the run away winner at this point.  It may change in the future but for now, looks like a winner.

Comment: Note that "The Library" is currently winning, but room names need to be unique and that name is already in use.  No other name has a significant lead at this point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While I like (and upvoted) [Chad's suggestion](https://ebooks.meta.stackexchange.com/a/68/318) of *The Prologue*, considering the fact that chat is part of the long tail of things you learn about after getting started on the main site rather than what you get up front, I thought maybe *The Epilogue* would be more appropriate. For some reason that didn't have the right ring to it*, but the more common parlance seems to fit the bill:

#### The Appendix

Alternatively, quirky variants such as **Appendix E** might fit the bill just as well.

* <sub>R.I.P. ongoing discussion.</sub>

Comment: +1 For Appendix E

Answer (score 7):

My suggestion:

**The Library**

Comment: I thought chatting in a library is frowned upon.

Comment: I was going to go with "The Library"

Comment: @Anthon - not in eLibrary :) Also, if you don't mind, I'm calling you Madam Pince from now on :)

Comment: @DVK Thanks. I had to look up that name, of course the rest of my family knew without that. Maybe I have to reread the (e-)books.

Comment: I think an alternative spelling to this would be more appropriate - The Librar-E

Comment: Unfortunately there is already another room on the network called The Library that has been in use for a couple years. In order for this to be practical, the Biblical Hermeneutics site would need to find another name for their chat.

Comment: Based on what @Caleb has said, I think we should go with `The Librar-E`, as Chad suggested. It's a nice workaround ;)

Comment: Down voting, as we can't use this name per @Caleb

Comment: @Chad Would you care to post your suggestion as an answer so it may be voted on?

Comment: @Caleb Bummer on that, could have been the perfect name for this site's chat room. I don't use that site so I didn't know the name of the chat room. Heck, I didn't even know that chat room names had to be unique.

Comment: @GrantPalin Technically I'm not sure they have to be, but for the sake of a lot of folks who are going to hang out in both it would be much appreciated if they didn't have ambiguous names in their room lists. It's also possible BH could be convinced to relinquish it. There are other options there, the 2 year history is the biggest glitch.

Answer (score 3):

**The Codex** [insert filler text here ;)]

Answer (score 1):

How about:

#### The Bitwise Press-Room

One consideration in evaluating names for the *main* chat room of an SE site is that there are several places where the name will be auto inserted by the system. The context of these substitutions will vary a lit but it is best not to bee too cryptic and to include some hint that the place might be a chat room it case that is not clear from context. One example is comments where you can include shorthand links like this:

> This comment thread has digressed, perhaps we could talk about this in [chat].

Something like 'The Lobby' or 'The Reading Room' will substitute well while something generic like 'E-Book Enthusists' or 'Digital Press' might not fare so well.

Answer (score 0):

My vote is for **Digital Press**.

Answer (score 0):

[**The Prologue**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prologue)

Answer (score 0):

As a riff on both Grant Palin's answer (which I like) and Anthon's quip that you shouldn't chat in a library, I give you:

**Library Lobby**.

Answer (score 0):

Just for kicks,

#### Periodical Appurtenance

Answer (score -2):

How about: **ebook enthusiasts**

Comment: I like this proposal

Answer (score -2):

**'The Reading Room'** would be my suggestion

Comment: That feels that it s more about the content

Answer (score -2):

How about using: **Digital Books**

Answer (score -2):

How about using: **The Open Book**

Answer (score -2):

**E-berry** (word and sound play) *E-Library*

Answer (score -3):

How about

1. ebookworms?
2. Electronic book readers?
3. eBookReaders?
4. Digital Read?
5. Go eBook Save Paper?

Comment: Please post a separate answer for each name suggestion.

Comment: Unfortunately "worm" has a slightly different connotation within the context of computer usage.